# i want to push that object in a new array where free is greater than 1

Tags: javascript, json, object

I want to use the json data to get an object from the json object where free has value greater than 0 and push that whole object in new array
for example i want to push {"free": 1, "used": 0,"total": 0, "usd_price": 0,} in to an array
and get a result like this [{"free": 1, "used": 0,"total": 0, "usd_price": 0},{"free": 1, "used": 0,"total": 0, "usd_price": 0}]

```
{
"success": true,
"messsage": "",
"data": {

    "BIT": {
    "free": 0,
    "used": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "usd_price": 0,
    "usd_val": 0,
    "percent_change_24h": 0,
    "usd_pnl_24h": 0,
    "name": "",
    "logo": "https://www.trailingcrypto.com/assets/img/default-coin.png",
    "portfolio_share": 0
    },

    "BTC": {
    "free": 0,
    "used": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "usd_price": 38400.82298054895,
    "usd_val": 0,
    "percent_change_24h": 0,
    "usd_pnl_24h": 0,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "logo": "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/128x128/1.png",
    "portfolio_share": 0
    },
    "DOT": {
    "free": 0,
    "used": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "usd_price": 20.07605927484185,
    "usd_val": 0,
    "percent_change_24h": 0,
    "usd_pnl_24h": 0,
    "name": "Polkadot",
    "logo": "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/128x128/6636.png",
    "portfolio_share": 0
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempt. Also your JSON is very hard to read. Please indent it properly.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do here is make use of Javascript's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to get  a sub-array that passes a given condition, which in your case is making sure that value of `free` is greater than 1. However the filter method can be applied only on an `array`, but the data you have provided is in the form of an `object`.

So before applying the `filter` method, let's convert this object into an array by using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```
Object.values(json.data)
```

Once you have the data in an array format, we can now apply the filter method to get a relevant subset from the original array (again, which in your case are the element where the value of free is greater than 1)

```
Object.values(json.data).filter((data) => data.free > 1)
```

And it should now work! Here is the full working code below

```js
const json = {
  success: true,
  messsage: "",
  data: {
    BIT: {
      free: 0,
      used: 0,
      total: 0,
      usd_price: 0,
      usd_val: 0,
      percent_change_24h: 0,
      usd_pnl_24h: 0,
      name: "",
      logo: "https://www.trailingcrypto.com/assets/img/default-coin.png",
      portfolio_share: 0,
    },

    BTC: {
      free: 0,
      used: 0,
      total: 0,
      usd_price: 38400.82298054895,
      usd_val: 0,
      percent_change_24h: 0,
      usd_pnl_24h: 0,
      name: "Bitcoin",
      logo: "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/128x128/1.png",
      portfolio_share: 0,
    },
    DOT: {
      free: 0,
      used: 0,
      total: 0,
      usd_price: 20.07605927484185,
      usd_val: 0,
      percent_change_24h: 0,
      usd_pnl_24h: 0,
      name: "Polkadot",
      logo: "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/128x128/6636.png",
      portfolio_share: 0,
    },
  },
};

const free = Object.values(json.data).filter((data) => data.free > 1);

console.log(free)
```

Answer (score 0):

put objects in array then loop through array and check if free is equal to one then if true push the object inside second array.

```
let dataFilter = [];
const res = {
  success: true,
  messsage: "",
  data: {
    BIT: {
   free: 0,
  used: 0,
  total: 0,
  usd_price: 0,
  usd_val: 0,
  percent_change_24h: 0,
  usd_pnl_24h: 0,
  name: "",
  logo: "https://www.trailingcrypto.com/assets/img/default-coin.png",
  portfolio_share: 0,
},

BTC: {
  free: 0,
  used: 0,
  total: 0,
  usd_price: 38400.82298054895,
  usd_val: 0,
  percent_change_24h: 0,
  usd_pnl_24h: 0,
  name: "Bitcoin",
  logo: "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/128x128/1.png",
  portfolio_share: 0,
},
DOT: {
  free: 1,
  used: 0,
  total: 0,
  usd_price: 20.07605927484185,
  usd_val: 0,
  percent_change_24h: 0,
  usd_pnl_24h: 0,
  name: "Polkadot",
  logo: "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/128x128/6636.png",
  portfolio_share: 0,
  },
 },
}

  Object.values(res.data).map((item) => {
   if (item?.free === 1) {
     console.log("ok");
     dataFilter.push(item);
   }
});
// now you have access data
console.log(dataFilter)
```

Comment: You should explain what you've done to solve the problem. Not just "try this".

Comment: @Andy ok, put objects in array then loop through array and check if free is equal to one then if true push the object inside second array.

Comment: You should add that to your answer, or comment your code, or both.